# Unable to connect to FTP sites

Tags: windows-7, ftp

Since a few days ago I am unable to connect to any FTP site neither through Windows's FTP client nor through other software like WinSCP. But I can login through command line FTP client. I am using Windows 7. ESET firewall is disabled and did not find any blocking rule in windows firewall. A symptom is when enter ftp://my-server.com in windows explorer address bar it says "windows cannot access the folder" and there is no further info in Details section.

Please help!